# Oracle rounding issue

Tags: oracle, plsql, rounding

I am using this code to round down the decimal value to the next multiple of 25.
ie if value is 33.60  it should round to 33.50

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE         "TEST1" (PQUERY IN VARCHAR2) as
 prNspValue number(14,2) :='';
 p_percentage_Value number(4,2) :='';
  begin
  prNspValue:=33.60;
  dbms_output.put_line(prNspValue); 
  p_percentage_Value:=substr(prNspValue,instr(prNspValue,'.')+1,length(prNspValue));
  dbms_output.put_line(p_percentage_value); 
  p_percentage_Value:=p_percentage_Value-mod(p_percentage_Value,25);
  dbms_output.put_line(p_percentage_value);
  if(p_percentage_Value!=0)then
    prNspValue:=substr(prNspValue,1,instr(prNspValue,'.'))+p_percentage_Value/100;
  else 
  prNspValue:=substr(prNspValue,1,instr(prNspValue,'.'));
  end if;
 dbms_output.put_line(prNspValue);     
end;
```

but the problem is when the  value is 33.60 it is taken as 33.6. so it is rounding it to 33.0.
How can i correct this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the round function directly `FLOOR(your_number*4)/4`:

```
SQL> WITH my_data AS (
  2     SELECT 33.00 num FROM dual
  3     UNION ALL SELECT 33.10 FROM dual
  4     UNION ALL SELECT 33.20 FROM dual
  5     UNION ALL SELECT 33.30 FROM dual
  6     UNION ALL SELECT 33.40 FROM dual
  7     UNION ALL SELECT 33.50 FROM dual
  8     UNION ALL SELECT 33.60 FROM dual
  9     UNION ALL SELECT 33.70 FROM dual
 10     UNION ALL SELECT 33.80 FROM dual
 11     UNION ALL SELECT 33.90 FROM dual
 12  ) SELECT num,
 13           floor (num * 4) / 4 rounded
 14      FROM my_data;

       NUM    ROUNDED
---------- ----------
        33         33
      33,1         33
      33,2         33
      33,3      33,25
      33,4      33,25
      33,5       33,5
      33,6       33,5
      33,7       33,5
      33,8      33,75
      33,9      33,75

10 rows selected
```

Comment: waht ever the case i want to round down..ie if its 33.9 it should give 33.75 etc..

Comment: @jasim: you can use `floor` instead of `round` to round down (I updated my answer)